# Fill NaN with condition on other column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Data:**

> ```
> col1       result 
>
>  good       positive 
>  bad        null
>  excellent  null
>  good       null        
>  good       null
> ```

**Required output:**

> ```
>  col1       result 
>
>  good       positive 
>  bad        positive
>  excellent  null
>  good       negative        
>  good       negative
> ```

I have following two condition and want to integrate it with `.fillna`, these condition apply only for `null` values in the `result` column

```
df = df.withColumn('result', when(col('col1') == 'good', 'negative').otherwise(df["result"]))
df = df.withColumn('result', when(col('col1') == 'bad', 'positive').otherwise(df["result"]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to replace nulls as desired:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Result', 
    F.coalesce(
        F.col('Result'),
        F.when(F.col('col1') == 'good', 'negative')
         .when(F.col('col1') == 'bad', 'positive')
    )
)

df2.show()
+---------+--------+
|     Col1|  Result|
+---------+--------+
|     good|positive|
|      bad|positive|
|excellent|    null|
|     good|negative|
|     good|negative|
+---------+--------+
```